# python error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' Парсинг новостей с хабра

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Код я скопировал с инета, только начинаю изучать bs4. В этом коде по идее должен выводится заголовок,url и описание с последнего поста на хабр'е. По другим вопросам тоже лазал, но там другие сайты.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://habr.com/ru/search/?target_type=posts&q=python&order_by=date"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("article", class_="tm-articles-list__item", id=True)
post_id = post["id"]
print(post_id)

title = post.find("a", class_="post__title_link").text.strip()
description = post.find("div", class_="post__text post__text-html post__text_v1").text.strip()
url = post.find("a", class_="post__title_link", href=True)["href"].strip()

print(title, description, url)
```

Comment: Проверь curl -ом что приходит, там нет ничего в ответе, выбрать тебе нужно другой инструмент, возможно Selenium, или что-то что будет исполнять скрипты. Или выбери другой сайт для тренировки.